# Check a column is empty array or not in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a json column which is set as null by default and casted as array in model.
I've used

```
->where('column_name', '\[\]')->get();
```

It retrun empty collection.

My question is if i've to check whether a column is empty array or not in where condition what will i do?

Comment: It will give you empty collection, because your `column_name` has no any null data. If it has array then use `whereIn` instead of `where`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599825/10573560)

```
where('column_name',DB::raw("json_array()"))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$records = Activity::query();
$records->where('properties->old','!=', '[]');
$records->skip($start)->take($rowperpage)->get();
```

this way it can be queried for JSON columns